# what is this filter contacts with side bar in ios named?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, filter

What object is this? What is the name of this object in the apple documentation? How can i go about adding this to my tableview?[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a comprehensive explanation about this in the documentation: ["Table View Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html), under the heading called "Populating an Indexed List"